# Calculating the size of a 2-level page table

Tags: memory, operating-system, paging, page-tables

So I have page sizes of `4kb`, `32` bit address CPU and an implemented 2-level page table.

I want to store 1081 pages, so I need:

1. `1024` entries in the 2-nd level page-table
2. `57` entries in another 2-nd level page table
3. A top level page table holding `2` entries.

Now, do I need to store in memory the full size of these page table or just what they occupy?

1. In the first case, I would then use `4bytes * 2 + 4bytes * 1024 + 4bytes * 57`
2. Otherwise it would be `1 * 4bytes * 1024 + 2 * 4bytes * 1024`

Any hint?

Comment: I would think this is entirely implementation specific based on the memory controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need 3 pages (or 12K) for your page table - one for the top level page, and two 2nd level pages.   Allocating just the space that is currently needed would be more complicated and likely slower than the alternative.

Check out Prof. Levy's [slides](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/08au/lectures/10-paging_TLBs.pdf) for some nice pictures on two level paging.